# Add Rows/Columns to a Grid dynamically

Tags: wpf, xaml, dynamic, user-controls, grid

I have a child `UserControl` comprising of multiple textboxes, labels, image etc. I need to populate this user control in a Parent User control which has a Grid.

The number of child user controls that need to be populated in the parent user control are determined at run time and can change. Basically the number depends on the search result. So it can be from 0 to n.

How can I populate my child user control in parent control? Or is there a better alternate to using a Grid control for this?

Note: I have to do this in my ViewModel.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To have a dynamic `Grid` size(column/row count), you can use helpers such as @Rachel 's [WPF Grid’s Row/Column Count Properties](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/)

In your case, this depends on what exactly your trying to achieve as in most simple cases based on context, when there is a requirement such as:

> Number of child user controls that need to be populated in the parent user control are determined at run time and can change. Basically the number depends on the search result. So it can be from 0 to n.

I'd prefer to go with an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) ([Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/)). Use the `ItemTemplate` to link to your child `UserControl`'s. If needed you can also tweak the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) to control layout as you see fit.

Comment: Excellent that is EXACTLY what I needed to do. Thanks bundles :)

Comment: I know its answered but to help others, please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.90).aspx#feedback