# I need my WPF grid control to be dynamically sizable (more or less rows and columns)

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, definition

i want to have the grid layout dynamic. pretty much the only modification needed is that i need sometimes more and less rows and columns. So the thing is, how do i access the row- & columndefinition in my c# class?

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <Grid Name="mygrid" Height="490">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Though with c# i am not getting to any solution. I tried with this attempt, though came to no conclusion

```
mygrid.ColumnDefinitions
```

Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Comment: `Grid` isn't really intended for that. Regardless, what was wrong with your attempt?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Which XAML control is better suited?

Comment: @RobertHarvey For dynamic layout? `StackPanel` for one. The only thing `Grid` buys you here is the even spacing, which you *can* write a custom panel for. It mostly depends on what he is *actually* trying to accomplish.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i want the layout to change i.e from 3x3 to a 4x4 so somehow i need to set this xaml line '<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>' in c# code in my class that i get the same result.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a `ColumnDefinition` object to the collection? I still don't understand what is going wrong with your attempt (regardless of whether or not its the correct approach)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET maybe my approach wasn't wrong, it's only i don't know how to write the proper line of code to add the object to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be straightforward to change the column definitions.  [`ColumnDefinitionCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinitioncollection(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IList<ColumnDefinition>`, so you can treat it like normal lists in .Net.

Add:

```
var newColumn = new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) };
mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newColumn);
```

Remove:

```
mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.RemoveAt(mygrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1);
```

(Note: you might also want to consider using an attached property to bind the number of rows/columns -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298255/1001985) for example.)