# WPF Grid Quick Way to Make Columns and Rows

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I need to make a  with 30 columns and 30 rows. Do I have to do `<ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>` and `<RowDefinition></RowDefinition>` for 30 times? Is there any easier/faster method?

Comment: You can always iterate through the list of column names and add the column using code behind

Comment: You can use `<ColumnDefinition />` copy 5x. Then select all 5 and hit `Ctrl+V` 6x. - shouldn't be to much of an effort.

Comment: Or you could try to cluster your view by separating parts into several usercontrols. that should save you some columns and rows !

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Maybe you're better off with another control and let it generate your cells with a template.

Comment: I am with @Lennart  on this; it sounds like you probably want to use another control entierly, like a `UniformGrid` or `StackPanel`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Rows/Columns to a Grid dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296889/add-rows-columns-to-a-grid-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to do `<ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>` and `<RowDefinition></RowDefinition>` for 30 times? Is there any easier/faster method?

Create them programmatically using a plain old for loop:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    const int n = 30;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" />
```

It can't be easier.